# WPF tracker multiple value

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

Currently, I have two line series for one plot model. I want to know if it's possible to have a tracker with multiple values like this example:

[image: Line image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There's no need for tags in your title. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles for more information. If you want to include tags, use them in the title (as you did with WPF).

Comment: Yes it's possible, but what charting components are you using?  Here's a suggestion put a browser in your application and use the asp.net charting.  MSFT dropped the ball with WPF Charting having only fully supported them in System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: @user1522548: He's using oxyplot, it's in the tags

Comment: I'm using oxyplot, i've one tracker per lineseries and I want to have on etracker for all series and I don't know if it's possible with oxyplot :).

Comment: It's hard to find a response to this problem :(

Answer (score 1):

I answered a question similar to this earlier:

[Oxyplot ScatterPoint custom Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497280/oxyplot-scatterpoint-custom-label/29965371#29965371)

I think you're after custom strings on each point for your tracker. I've explained this in my other answer but you pretty much want to include the Y values of the other series in your tags where your X value is the same.

Hope this helps!