# Oxyplot ScatterPoint custom Label

Tags: oxyplot

is it possible to write a custom string instead of the x and y position over a ScatterPoint?
I searched in the documentation and Google but sadly didn't find anything. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is my friend!

If you want the custom string to be the same for all points in the series, simply edit  the TrackerFormatString. The TrackerFormatString is in the series object.

If you want each point to have a separate string, add the tag to the custom string like so:

```
seriesToAdd.TrackerFormatString = seriesToAdd.TrackerFormatString + "{Tag}";
```

You can then edit the tag for each point in the series.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What result do you get in the Scatter Series?

Answer (score 0):

**Some necromancy:** If you wish to show labels next to points on the plot, `TrackerFormatString` will not help you (it is used in the tracker (tooltip) display, not on the chart surface).

To add labels directly on the chart you need to use `LabelFormatString`. If this is null no labels are shown, but once you assign a value the labels will appear above `ScatterPoint` items.

This string can contain plaintext that will be shown in the label, and variables within `{` `}` braces. Two positional variables are available: `{0}` for X and `{1}` for Y. You can also access any property of the scatter point `Item` - for example if you just use `ScatterPoint` objects, these have a `Tag`, so you can use `{Tag}` in the format string (as long as you assign a non-null value to the Tag property)

For example, to show the Y value: `LabelFormatString = "{1:0.00}"`.

Adding text like the point's name to the label is harder. You have to use the `ItemsSource` rather than `Points`, and each `Item` from that source represents one point and the metadata you need to display the label text. For example, we can use `ScatterPoint` objects:

- Create `ScatterPoint` objects, setting their `Tag` to the label text you wish to use,
- Add them to a list and assign or bind it to `ItemsSource`.
- Set (e.g.) `LabelFormatString="{Tag}"` or `"{Tag} {1:0.0} {2:0.000}"`

You can also include plaintext within the format string or even `Environment.Newline` to make a multi-line label.